# Infinite product integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{2^k}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, infinite-product

The integral is the following :
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\bigg(\frac{x}{2^k}\bigg)dx$$

I need first to evaluate this product, but how ?

My attempts :

Using :
$$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x) \Leftrightarrow \cos(x)=\frac{\sin(2x)}{2\sin(x)}$$
So basically this can help us : 
$$\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\big(\frac{x}{2^k}\big)}{2\sin\big(\frac{x}{2^k}\big)} =\frac{\sin x}{2\sin(x/2)}\frac{\sin (x/2)}{2\sin(x/4)}\color{red}{\dots}$$
It's important to eveluate this product but I couldn't any hints ? I'll be thankfull !

Comment: Can you see how infinitely many terms can cancel in this telescoping product? As you have shown correctly$$\prod_{k=1}^n\cos{\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right)}=\frac{\sin{(x)}}{2^n\sin{(x/2^n)}}\to\frac{\sin{(x)}}x$$so the integral is just the Dirichlet integral namely equal to $\pi$.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn7z9T-dezw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$\frac{\sin x}x =\frac{\sin \frac x2 }{\frac x2}\cos\frac x2 
= \frac{\sin \frac x{2^2}}{ \frac x{2^2}} \cos\frac x{2^2}\cos\frac x2 \\
= \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\sin \frac x{2^n}}{\frac x{2^n}}\right)\cos\frac{x}{2^n}...\cos\frac x{2^2}\cos\frac x2 = \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{2^k}
$$ 
where $ \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t} =1$ is used. Thus,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos\frac{x}{2^k}dx= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}x dx = \pi
$$